# how to pass returned fetch data to a reducer using redux saga

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I'm doing a fetch request that makes a new user in my database. All of it works and a new user is made/api-key returned.

The problem is that i am unable to pass the received response of my fetch request to my reduces. 
I'm wondering if I should call another action as a response to my successful fetch request that triggers a reducer and takes the response of the request as payload.

Or if I am able to pass the response of the fetch request to the reducer instantly. 
Here is my SAGA:

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest, delay } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {REGISTER} from '../redux/actions/loginAPIcall'

function* callAPIregister(){ 
    const json = yield fetch('http://spotlight-api.local/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: 'apptest3',
          email: 'apptest3@test.be',
          password: '123456789'
        }),
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                  console.log(data)
              })
    yield put({type: 'REGISTER_SAGA', payload: json})
}

export function* watchAPIcall(){
    yield takeEvery(REGISTER, callAPIregister)
}
```

and below is my reducer:

```
import {REGISTER, LOGIN} from '../actions/loginAPIcall'

const initialState = {
    apiCalling: false, 
    occupation: null
}

function addAPIcall(state = initialState, action, payload){
    console.log('inside the api reducer')
    switch(action.type){
        case "REGISTER_SAGA":
            console.log('inside register_saga reducer', payload)
            return {
                apiCalling: true,
                occupation: 'REGISTER'
                }
        case LOGIN:
            return {
                apiCalling: true,
                occupation: 'LOGIN'
            }
        default:
            return state;
            }
}
export default addAPIcall
```

when loggin the reducer payload now it says undefined.

Comment: You need to yield one more action inside the success callback of the promise once you receive the response. Then read that action in your reducer.

Comment: I think you can move that fetch part in one other function which will return the API data, collect that data in callApiRegister generator function, it'll clear out the code. In callApiRegister use try catch block, and in reducer you can get its value by using action.<variable-name>

Comment: Let me write in answer so that you'll get to know.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` by itself will wait until Promise is resolved if Promise will be returned from the yielded statement. So correct `callAPIregister` will be

```
function* callAPIregister(){ 
    // yield will wait for Promise to resolve
    const response = yield fetch('http://spotlight-api.local/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: 'apptest3',
          email: 'apptest3@test.be',
          password: '123456789'
        }),
      })
    // Again yield will wait for Promise to resolve
    const data = yield response.json()
    console.log(data)
    yield put({type: 'REGISTER_SAGA', payload: data})
}
```

And also I recommend to consider [using `call`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html) in `yield` statements. It is for easier unit testing

Comment: thanks for your answer. It says that response is not defined.

Comment: I;ve created simple project to showcase how it works with test REST API https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-saha-g4ejp. Saga works as expected. In you case, `fetch` can be called with incorrect arguments

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this thing will work for you. Made 'FETCH_FAILED' type well if there's any error in fetching then you can catch that error. So, make one more variable in your reducers initial_state object.

sagas.js

```
import { call, put, takeLatest, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {REGISTER} from '../redux/actions/loginAPIcall';

function getData(payload){
    return fetch('http://spotlight-api.local/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => json)
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
}

function* callAPIregister(){ 
  try{
    const payload = {
      name: 'apptest3',
      email: 'apptest3@test.be',
      password: '123456789'
    }
    const response = yield call(getData, payload);

    //In this please check what is the name of your data variable
    //Eg if its message then you can
    console.log(response);
    //use response: response.message
    yield put({type: 'REGISTER_SAGA', response: response})
  } catch (error){
    yield put({ type: 'FETCH_FAILED', error });
  }
}

export function* watchAPIcall(){
    yield takeEvery(REGISTER, callAPIregister)
}
```

In your reducer you can create a variable in initial state object and then in your 'REGISTER_SAGA' capture the data that we got from our saga

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    apiCalling: false, 
    occupation: null,
    data: []
}

case "REGISTER_SAGA":
        console.log('inside register_saga reducer', payload)
        return {
            apiCalling: true,
            occupation: 'REGISTER',
            data: action.response
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { takeEvery, put, call } from "redux-saga/effects";   
import { AnyAction } from "redux";

const users = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Keshav Gera",
      email: "Keshav.Gera@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Happy Gera",
      email: "Happy.Gera@gmail.com"
    }
  ];
  yield put(getUsersSuccess({ users }));
```